# Selenium java how to get JS file sizes from Network tab after login

Tags: javascript, java, file-io, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I am fairly new to Selenium so please bear with me.  I have a requirement to check two JS file sizes upon login of an application (Open chrome browser -> Open Url -> Click in username and input username -> Click in password textbox and input password -> Click submit button -> Verify upon page load the two js file sizes).

Once the initial page loads after login and initial page load, I am to capture the vendor*.js and client*.js file sizes and verify that they meet a specific threshold (vendor*.js max size = 2MB, client*.js max size = 500kB).  How is this possible when interacting with Chrome browser?  Below is a snapshot of the responses in the Network tab that show these js files and their header properties:

[image: Network tab]

Given this, is there a way to use javascript executor and execute a js function to get this?  Is there another way through java and also using selenium for all the steps in order to get to this point?  Please let me know as any suggestions would help.  Thanks!!